# Rice's theorem applicable to the following language?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability, undecidability, rice-theorem

Let $L= \{\langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ halts on } \langle M \rangle \} $
be a language where $\langle M \rangle$ is the Code of the TM $M$. $L$ is undecidable.

I've heard that I can't use Rice's theorem to proof its undecidability.

But why? I can construct a set $S = \{f_M \mid f_M(\langle M \rangle)\in \{0,1\}\}$.

It's clear that $S$ is not empty and $S$ contains not every TM.

Comment: What are $f_m$ and $f_M$? (I assume one of them is a typo, but what does the other one mean?)

Comment: both should be f_M. It describes the function of the Turing Machine M. 1 and 0 stands for accept or reject. For example the TM M' that accepts everything has the function f_M'(x) = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there may be multiple $M$'s corresponding to the same $f_M$. That is to say, you cannot deduce $\langle M\rangle$ from $f_M$, so you cannot describe $S$ in this way.